# Wifi blocking the network calls from my app using retrofit and okhttp

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have created an Android app using retrofit and Okhttp for network calls. The one API request behaves differently for different wifi's. Sometimes I get socketTimeOutException and sometimes connectionTimeOut. Then I figured out that the wifi I was using was blocking the API calls due to the firewall.Although the API request goes through the postman client successfully. I am not able to understand that why it is not happening through my android app.

The format of the URL is something like this :

> http://www.xyz.co:5050/api/v5/scanning

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue on Android 7+. It seems on the bug in OkHttp as described [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3974)